# Removing username from the 'wordpress_logged_in' cookie

Tags: login, cookies, session

I am working with a client with some strict security measures. After undergoing security review, we were notified that the user name stored in the logged in cookie, e.g.

`wordpress_logged_in[username]|[hash]`

is something that has to be removed. Since this is an integral part of the login system, I'm not sure how to remove it and still maintain the session.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Short introduction

After quick look inside WP source code, I think I've found solution...

WordPress uses two functions to set and parse auth cookies:

- `wp_generate_auth_cookie`
- `wp_parse_auth_cookie`

There is a filter in `wp_generate_auth_cookie` called `auth_cookie` which you probably could use to change the contents of cookie, but there is no filter inside `wp_parse_auth_cookie`, but...

Both of these functions are defined in pluggable.php, which means, that you can write your own implementations for them and overwrite default ones.

### Solution

1. Write your own plugin (let's call it Better Auth Cookie)
2. Implement your own `wp_generate_auth_cookie` and `wp_parse_auth_cookie` functions inside this plugin.
3. Activate your plugin.

You can find my sample implementation (based strongly on original versions) of these functions below:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_generate_auth_cookie') ) :
/**
 * Generate authentication cookie contents.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param int $user_id User ID
 * @param int $expiration Cookie expiration in seconds
 * @param string $scheme Optional. The cookie scheme to use: auth, secure_auth, or logged_in
 * @param string $token User's session token to use for this cookie
 * @return string Authentication cookie contents. Empty string if user does not exist.
 */
function wp_generate_auth_cookie( $user_id, $expiration, $scheme = 'auth', $token = '' ) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    if ( ! $user ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( ! $token ) {
        $manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user_id );
        $token = $manager->create( $expiration );
    }

    $pass_frag = substr($user->user_pass, 8, 4);

    $key = wp_hash( $user->user_login . '|' . $pass_frag . '|' . $expiration . '|' . $token, $scheme );

    // If ext/hash is not present, compat.php's hash_hmac() does not support sha256.
    $algo = function_exists( 'hash' ) ? 'sha256' : 'sha1';
    $hash = hash_hmac( $algo, $user->user_login . '|' . $expiration . '|' . $token, $key );

    $cookie = $user_id . '|' . $expiration . '|' . $token . '|' . $hash;

    /**
     * Filter the authentication cookie.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param string $cookie     Authentication cookie.
     * @param int    $user_id    User ID.
     * @param int    $expiration Authentication cookie expiration in seconds.
     * @param string $scheme     Cookie scheme used. Accepts 'auth', 'secure_auth', or 'logged_in'.
     * @param string $token      User's session token used.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'auth_cookie', $cookie, $user_id, $expiration, $scheme, $token );
}
endif;


if ( !function_exists('wp_parse_auth_cookie') ) :
/**
 * Parse a cookie into its components
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 *
 * @param string $cookie
 * @param string $scheme Optional. The cookie scheme to use: auth, secure_auth, or logged_in
 * @return array Authentication cookie components
 */
function wp_parse_auth_cookie($cookie = '', $scheme = '') {
    if ( empty($cookie) ) {
        switch ($scheme){
            case 'auth':
                $cookie_name = AUTH_COOKIE;
                break;
            case 'secure_auth':
                $cookie_name = SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE;
                break;
            case "logged_in":
                $cookie_name = LOGGED_IN_COOKIE;
                break;
            default:
                if ( is_ssl() ) {
                    $cookie_name = SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE;
                    $scheme = 'secure_auth';
                } else {
                    $cookie_name = AUTH_COOKIE;
                    $scheme = 'auth';
                }
        }

        if ( empty($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) )
            return false;
        $cookie = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }

    $cookie_elements = explode('|', $cookie);
    if ( count( $cookie_elements ) !== 4 ) {
        return false;
    }

    list( $user_id, $expiration, $token, $hmac ) = $cookie_elements;

    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $username = ( ! $user ) ? '' : $user->user_login;

    return compact( 'username', 'expiration', 'token', 'hmac', 'scheme' );
}
endif;
```

My version of these functions replaces `user_login` with `user_id`. But it should be a good start for changing it to something even more complex (i.e. user specific hash, or something like this).

Comment: Nice answer. Though I'll wait until the last day of my bounty period. :)

Comment: I'm going to accept this, although I won't be testing it as I no longer need this solution. You clearly put a lot of effort in to digging to the root of the system, I appreciate the effort :)

Comment: While this approach is a good one, you should be aware that it affords no more protection. The username is substituted for the user ID, but the username can be gotten from the user ID via a request to `example.com?author=123`, which performs a canonical redirect to a URL such as `example.com/author/john`.

Comment: @john read carefully please. I've mentioned, that you can easily make it much more secure storing some random hash in cookie instead of userID.