# Check if a user is connected and get is ID without fully loading wordpress

Tags: cache

I'm writing an advanced cache for WP. I try to make it works with connected users. I want to calculate a [user context hash](http://foshttpcache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-context.html#calculating-the-user-context-hash).

To build my hash I need a way to quickly know if the user is logged and get is user ID from advanced-cache.php. So before WP is fully loaded. After with is user ID I can simply do a SQL query to know is role and build the hash with this information.

I read wp_validate_auth_cookie and other related functions without finding how I'm suppose to use that.

Comment: AFAIR there is user_login encoded in auth cookie. Will it help?

Comment: Not really because anyone can send a fake cookies with the username. It needs to be properly checked as a valid cookie.

Comment: Well, not anybody. WP auth cookie is signed, so you can easily check if it's fake or not.

Comment: I see. But how I do that? I didn't find a proper documentation explaining the system.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress stores user_name of logged in user in auth cookie. Auth cookie is signed, so it's easy to check if it's fake, so you can trust this info.

OK, so how to get user's user_name from cookie?

There is function for that ;)

[wp_parse_auth_cookie](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_auth_cookie)

and this is what it returns:

```
return compact( 'username', 'expiration', 'token', 'hmac', 'scheme' );
```

So you can use something like this:

```
$cookie = wp_parse_auth_cookie( '', 'logged_in' );
$user_name = $cookie['username']
```

to get user_name of user that is currently logged in.

If you need he's ID and not user_name, then use DB to retrieve it or change content of the auth cookie (here's how: [Removing username from the 'wordpress_logged_in' cookie](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177473/removing-username-from-the-wordpress-logged-in-cookie/191062#191062)).

Comment: It doesn't work without loading WP. I need to do that in an completely independent PHP file (but I'm ok to include some WP file)

Comment: But what's the problem. This info is in ten cookie. I've shown you, how WP uses this cookie, so just take a look at this function and do it by yourself...